# Distinct Households Comparison Using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am trying to compare two lists of unique Household IDs using the Distinct clause. The problem comes when I try to pull in a third column consisting of timestamps into the results.

When I include only the two Household ID columns in the Select statement, the results seem to make sense. I get back two lists of unique IDs.

Here is that query:

```
select distinct e.household_id, a.hhid
FROM [dbo].[exposure] e
left outer join [dbo].[audience] a
on e.household_id = a.hhid
```

However, when I just add the "e.imp_ts" column to the Select statement, it looks like SQL completely disregards the Distinct part of the query and pulls in all the duplicate households in the files.

```
select distinct e.household_id, a.hhid, e.imp_ts
FROM [dbo].[exposure] e
left outer join [dbo].[audience] a
on e.household_id = a.hhid
```

Can someone please explain why the query doesn't work when I simply add a third column to the Select statement?

Thank you!

Comment: The `distinct` applies to the entire row, not the first field. Add some data samples and expected result.

Comment: How are you determining that SQL Server knows what columns you expect the `distinct` to apply to? Presumably you have different timestamps which are also distinct per row... You probably need to `group` and aggregate.

Comment: Being that those 'duplicate' rows have differing `imp_ts` values, what exactly do you want to do with those multiple values to fit them into a single row? Take the minimum value, maximum value, something else?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not that the second query "doesn't work", but rather that it is being asked to provide different results than the first query. As others in the comments have pointed out, because the `imp_ts` column contains more granular data, the distinct can no longer return a unique list of household IDs. For example, household ID 12345 may contain 5 records, each with unique timestamps on them.

In order to resolve this, you have some choices:

1. Remove `imp_ts` from the query.
2. Return the minimum (most likely first) timestamp
3. Return the maximum (most likely last) timestamp

For #2 and #3 above, you can use `MIN()` or `MAX()` with a `GROUP BY` to achieve those results. Here is an example of using `MIN()`:

```
select e.household_id, a.hhid, MIN(e.imp_ts) AS min_imp_ts
FROM [dbo].[exposure] e
left outer join [dbo].[audience] a
on e.household_id = a.hhid
group by e.household_id, a.hhid
```

I would suggest looking up GROUP BY examples online to get a better idea of what is happening.